# How does ruby differentiate between single and double quoted strings? Are C pointers involved?

Tags: ruby, string, object

Does anyone know how the ruby interpreter knows the difference between a string literal (single quoted string) and a double quoted string?

I am playing with strings and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to change them from one to the other.

I was able to do this to some extent, by replacing escape sequences inside the string to their respective ascii code.

```
\n = 10 -> \\ = 92, n = 110
```

I took this double quoted string

```
"a\e[0;36m X \n"
```

which when interpreted would result in

```
 a X
```

with the X displayed with a cyan font color. And I changed the escape sequences into letters preceded by a backslash. This only works when the passed string is a double string. I haven't had any luck passing a single quoted string and changing it to double quoted so I can allow interpolation. And in the end I haven't really change the string just it's contents so it behaves that way.

This has now gotten me interested in figuring out how ruby knows when a string is single quoted vs double quoted.  I am sure that it has a mechanism for doing this because when I was playing in IRB I did this.

```
a = "One\nTwo\t Half\n"
=> "One\nTwo\t Half\n"
b = 'Three \n Four \f Five'
=> "Three \\n Four \\f Five"
puts a + b
One
Two  Half
Three \n Four \f Five
=> nil
c = a + b
One
Two  Half
Three \n Four \f Five
=> nil
```

So as you can see ruby is smart enough to remember that certain chunks of the string are single quoted and others are double quoted. I am curious to find out if ruby is keeping references/pointers to the original strings and when strings are added they are simply chained together, because it doesn't seem like it is creating a new string.

<strike>Another curious thing I've noticed is that there is no way to return string literals from a method/function. If there is can anyone point me to this.</strike> Let's leave this for another question.

Update:

I am now playing with

```
ObjectSpace._id2ref(obj.object_id)
```

So from the above example I tried this.

```
a.object_id
=> 70219586904340
puts ObjectSpace._id2ref 70219586904340
One
Two  Half
=> nil
b.object_id
=> 70219590675520
puts ObjectSpace._id2ref 70219590675520
Three \n Four \f Five
=> nil
c = a + b
puts ObjectSpace._id2ref c.object_id
One
Two  Half
Three \n Four \f Five
=> nil
```

I am now playing the objects but I can't find it yet.  I want to see inside see and see objA + objB or something to that extent.

Comment: “ruby is smart enough to remember”—ruby does remember nothing, the parser takes care of escaping anything in single quotes strings.

Comment: *I am curious to find out if ruby is keeping references/pointers to the original strings and when strings are added they are simply chained together, because it doesn't seem like it is creating a new string.* -- `puts some_string.object_id` and have a look.

Comment: The answer to your second question in the subject is obvious: no, C pointers cannot possibly be involved, as is evidenced by the fact that non-C-based Ruby implementations exist (Opal written in ECMAScript and Ruby, Ruby.NET and IronRuby written in C♯, JRuby and XRuby written in Java, Cardinal written in NQP and PASM, …).

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference, interpreter-wise. Single and double quoted strings only exist at the parser level<sup>1</sup>. If the parser encounters single quotes, it parses the characters literally:

```
str = 'foo\nbar' #=> "foo\\nbar"
str.chars        #=> ["f", "o", "o", "\\", "n", "b", "a", "r"]
str.codepoints   #=> [102, 111, 111,  92,  110, 98,  97,  114]
```

If the parser encounters double quotes, it translates several escape sequences to their respective characters (e.g. the sequence `\n` to the ASCII character with codepoint 10, i.e. newline):

```
str = "foo\nbar" #=> "foo\nbar"
str.chars        #=> ["f", "o", "o", "\n", "b", "a", "r"]
str.codepoints   #=> [102, 111, 111,  10,  98,  97,  114]
```

You can even mix single quotes and double quotes:

```
str = 'foo' "\n" 'bar'
#=> "foo\nbar"
```

The parsers treats it as a single string literal `"foo\nbar"`.

Either way, there are no *"single quoted string instances"* and *"double quoted string instances"*, just string instances.

Ruby gives you several literals to create strings (`'...'`, `"..."`, `%q{...}`, `<<HEREDOC`, `?...`). The resulting objects are all alike.

---

<sup>1</sup> internally there is `NODE_STR` for static strings and `NODE_DSTR` for interpolated strings, but you can't access that level from within Ruby. Once you have a string instance, it's merely a bunch of characters.

Comment: Very interesting, as always. `str = 'foo' "\n" 'bar'`. Wow. With so many different acceptable syntaxes, I'm surprised there still are syntax errors in Ruby.

Comment: This great to know.  The parser does differentiate between the two.

Comment: But how does there interpreter keep track that part of  `objC` is single quoted and part is double quoted. From the above example, remember  `c = a + b`.  So we have a NODE_STR + NODE_DSTR.  Is the resulting string NODE_STR or NODE_DSTR?  I have a suspicion that every returned and/or concatenated string is a NODE_DSTR.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @luis.madrigal no, both are `NODE_STR`, because no interpolation takes place in `"One\nTwo\t Half\n"`. But again, `NODE_STR` and `NODE_DSTR` are intermediate structures in Ruby's (implementation specific) internal parse tree. These are not Ruby objects.

Answer (score -1):

> Another curious thing I've noticed is that there is no way to return
>   string literals from a method/function. If there is can anyone point
>   me to this.

```
def do_stuff
  "hello"
end

puts do_stuff.class
puts do_stuff
p do_stuff


--output:--
String
hello
"hello"
```

Comment: I am pretty sure, person asking such question does know how to return a string from a method ;). What OP might have meant by this is that you can't return a single quoted string from a method.